# Lubuntu installation gets stuck

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, uefi, lenovo

I am trying to install Lubuntu 17.10 alongside the pre-installed Windows 10 on my Lenovo Miix 320. It seems that to get the live boot work I have to enable secure boot and disable Intel platform trust technology from UEFI settings.
(When trying to boot from USB, there is a message *error: file '/boot/' not found* just before grub.)

The live session seems to run well, and also the install process seems promising in the beginning. However, the installation gets stuck at some point with the console looping with messages

```
power_supply axp288_fuel_gauge: driver failed to report 'charge_now' property: -6

axp288_fuel_gauge axp288_fuel_gauge: capacity measurement not valid

axp288_fuel_gauge axp288_fuel_gauge: Error 0xe2 contents not valid
```

Any tips would be appreciated.